# Set focus to dynamically created input in reactive form angular

Tags: javascript, html, angular, angular-reactive-forms, autofocus

First toggle Items to yes, then click on "add row" button. New row will be created, it should always set focus on last created *name* input field.
Here is the stackblitz link [set focus on name field](https://stackblitz.com/edit/dynamically-add-rows-gk4veg?file=app%2Fapp.component.html)

[Picture depicts the scenario](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7qVgj.png)

Answer (score 0):

You can create custom directive to get input element reference then call focus method on it.

**Try this:**

```
import { Directive,ElementRef } from '@angular/core';
import { AfterViewInit } from '@angular/core/src/metadata';

@Directive({
  selector: '[appAutoFocus]'
})
export class AutoFocusDirective implements AfterViewInit {

  constructor(private element:ElementRef) {}

   ngAfterViewInit(){
     this.element.nativeElement.focus();
   }
}
```

[Forked Working Stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/dynamically-add-rows-dxrsrf?file=app/auto-focus.directive.ts)

Comment: Should probably use AfterContentInit instead, to avoid "expression changed after checked" error.